# Can't play on the same game

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So my three kids all have Minecraft PE v0.15.6.0 but they cannot play on the same world... We have tried everything, they are all on the same wifi, two are trying on IPhone 5S and one on an iPad. Any help?

Comment: Make sure you are all on the same version. What does it say/look like when you try to join?

Comment: What kind of WiFi setting are you using? You could have potentially configured so that devices cannot locally connect each other which is a safety feature.

Answer (score 1):

First, go to settings and then set local multiplayer or LAN to be turned on, on all the devices and then you can join the game together.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the Minecraft options allow multiplayer games.